# Verwendet man Abkürzungen in (technischen) Texten?

Tags: usage, writing

Ich schreibe als Software-Entwickler viele Dokumente, meist technischer Natur (doch halbwegs verständlich für Nichttechniker), aber auch "direktorensicher". Dabei geht es mir nicht um ein paar Tabellen mit kurzen Sätzen, sondern um richtigen Fließtext. Prosa. Sagt man jedenfalls bei uns dazu.

Hier fällt mir oft auf, dass ich Abkürzungen, soweit möglich, vermeide, während viele Kollegen sehr viele Abkürzungen verwenden. Ich meine damit die ganzen kleinen Abkürzungen wie:

- bzw. (beziehungsweise)
- ggf. (gegebenenfalls)
- z. B. (zum Beispiel)
- s. o. / s. u. (siehe oben / siehe unten)

und ähnliche (Liste kann gerne ergänzt werden, die fielen mir nur gerade ein).

Ich finde, dass diese Abkürzungen den Textfluss immer wieder unterbrechen und schreibe sie selbst daher aus. Häufig sagt eine Verwendung dieser Wörter auch, dass man den Satz noch umformulieren könnte (statt *siehe oben* zum Beispiel *siehe Kapitel 2.4*). Mir sind dazu bisher keine nennenswerten Regeln untergekommen. Kann ich gefahrlos diese Abkürzungen im Fließtext immer ausschreiben? Sollte ich sie korrigieren, wenn ich sie in einem Text finde, den ich korrekturlese?

---

As software developer, I write a lot of documents, mostly technical (though they should be kind of readable by non-technicians), and also some PHB-safe documents. I'm not talking about some tables with short sentences, but continuous text.

I try to avoid abbreviations/acronyms if possible, while co-workers tend to use them a lot. I'm talking about the little ones like:

- bzw. (beziehungsweise)
- ggf. (gegebenenfalls)
- z. B. (zum Beispiel)
- s. o. / s. u. (siehe oben / siehe unten)

and similar (feel free to expand the list).

In my opinion, these abbreviations/acronyms break the text flow, so I typically spell them in full. Many times, using these words can also mean that the sentence can be improved (e.g. *siehe Kapitel 2.4* instead of *siehe oben*). I don't know good rules for this. Should I just spell these out in full? Should I correct them when correcting a text written by someone else?

Comment: +1 thanks for teaching me ggf. as gegebenenfalls .

Comment: Als Softwareentwickler bist du faul und schreibst sie nicht aus ;)

Comment: @Em1: Du hast mich noch nie tippen sehen, sonst kämst du nicht auf dergestalt sonderbare Gedanken. Ich schreibe grundsätzlich alles aus und bin dabei trotzdem schneller als die Abkürzer - im Code wie in Dokumentation ;) Allerdings kann ich dir insofern Recht geben, als dass ich auch davon ausgehe, dass es typische Softwareentwicklerfaulheit ist, alles abzukürzen...

Answer (score 7):

Bei diesen seit langem gebräuchlichen Abkürzungen ist es ziemlich egal, ob man sie ausschreibt. Sie stören nicht den Lesefluss.

Comment: Meinen Lesefluss stören sie. Natürlich ist das auch subjektiv, klar. Andererseits kann man deine Antwort auch klar so auffassen, dass ich weiterhin alles ausschreiben kann :)

Comment: Richtig, es gibt keinen Grund warum du dies nicht tun solltest, wenn dir danach ist.

Comment: Aber fremde Texte korrigieren würde ich auch nicht. Würde ich sowieso nicht, weil ich auch finde, dass es den Lesefluß nicht stört.

Comment: *Sehr* gebräuchliche Abkürzungen auszuschreiben kann stören.  Nicht unbedingt den Lese*fluss*, aber das Verständnis.  "Too much boilerplate" sagen Programmierer gern mal zu sowas. :D

Answer (score 5):

Im technischen Bereich sind diese Abkürzungen üblich. Mit "technisch" meine ich Diplomarbeiten, Dissertationen, Dokumentationen, etc. pp. (nur mal eben als Beispiel :-)

Bei Prosatexten (z.B. Romane) sollte man sie tunlichst vermeiden.

Allerdings, wenn man sie verwendet, sollte man es richtig machen. Bei meinem "zum Beispiel" oben ist es zum Beispiel verkehrt. Zwischen "z." und "B." gehört ein Leerzeichen und zwar eines, das etwas kürzer ist, als das normale und das auch keinen Zeilenumbruch zuläßt.

```
Denn das sieht z.
Bsp. bescheuert aus.
```

Comment: Deshalb habe ich auch in meinem Beispiel oben ein Leerzeichen gesetzt. In erster Näherung ist ein normales Leerzeichen sicherlich akzeptabel. Aber du hast recht, ein geschütztes Leerzeichen wäre besser. Kürzt man nicht ab, muss man sich damit aber gar nicht beschäftigen :)

Comment: Das Prosa in der Frage bezieht sich nicht auf Prosa-Texte wie Romane, sondern ist in manchen Entwicklerkreisen ein Spitzname für Texte die zum Einen nicht unbedingt für Entwicklerkollegen bestimmt sind, und zum anderen in Fließtextform verfasst werden - also keine Aufzählungslisten, Tabellen, Changelogs oder API-Dokus, wohl aber Handbücher, Essays, Konzepte, E-Mails und "politische" Abhandlungen (also schriftliche Diskussionen ohne technischen Hintergrund).

Answer (score 4):

Wenn es nur um persönlichen Geschmack geht, halte ich Abkürzungen bei langen Wörtern durchaus für tauglich. *bzw.* lässt sich meiner Meinung nach viel besser parsen als *beziehungsweise*. *z. B.* hingegen kann gerne ausgeschrieben werden (stört mich abgekürzt aber kein bisschen).

Es kommt wie so oft auch auf die Leser an. In meiner Abschlussarbeit habe ich Abkürzungen immer verwendet, nachdem ich das mit meinem Professor abgesprochen habe.

Davon abgesehen: Als Software-Entwickler müsste man Abkürzungen ja gewohnt sein. ;)

Comment: Ja, als Software-Entwickler ist man Abkürzungen gewohnt (wobei. Intellisense, anyone? :P), aber meine Leserschaft ist wie erwähnt ja in der Regel nicht (oder nicht so weitgehend) technisch vorgebildet.

Comment: Dann empfiehlt sich ersten ein Glossar, und zweitens bei erstmaliger Benutzung die Abkürzung zu erläutern, z.B. würde ich HTML (Hyper-Text-Markup-Language) einmal erläutern, und dabei gleich die Abkürzung vorstellen, die ich im folgenden verwende. Wenn das Wort auf 600 Seiten nur 2x vorkommt, und dazwischen 350 Seiten liegen, vielleicht auch nicht. Die Geläufigkeit der Abkürzung spielt natürlich eine wichtige Rolle.

Comment: Nun, in der Frage ging es ja eher um Abkürzungen wie *z. B.* oder *bzw.* Die gehören m. E. nach nicht in ein Glossar. Dann lieber ausschreiben. Für technische Begriffe halte ich ein Glossar und evtl. Ausschreiben bei erster Benutzung aber für angemessen.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kann nur von meiner persönlichen Erfahrung sprechen (Ebenfalls Software-Entwickler mit viel Dokumentation) und dieser folgend schreibe ich die meisten gängigen Abkürzungen (wie du auch) aus. Bisher hat sich noch keiner der Lektoren darüber beschwert, genauso wenig wie die Professoren, die sie bewerten.

Meiner Meinung nach kommt dies, gerade in etwas anspruchsvolleren Texten, einem angenehmen Lesen desselbigen sehr zu gute. Wie du bereits erwähnt hast, unterbrechen Abkürzungen und Akronyme den Lesefluss enorm.

Anders sieht es mit technischen Abkürzungen aus (gerade bei uns Software-Leuten sind ja Begriffe wie HTML, C#, OOP, ORM, DBMS und Konsorten sehr häufig anzutreffen). Diese schreibe ich nur einmal komplett aus und verwende danach den Kurznamen. Ich finde das ist wesentlich "natürlicher" zu lesen, als wenn man jedes mal die komplette Bezeichnung durchlesen muss (was gerade bei Begriffen wie AJAX, HTML oder XSLT wirklich lange Wortketten sind).

Ich glaube nicht, dass sich jemand arg daran stören wird, dass du sie ausschreibst, aber auf der anderen ist gerade bei solch "altbekannten" Abkürzungen wie usw., bzw. etc. (!) die Gefahr doch eher gering, dass sich jemand beim Lesen an deren Aufkommen stört.

Comment: Was die technischen Abkürzungen angeht: Unsere Dokumentenvorlage enthält zu Beginn zwei Tabellen zu Abkürzungen und Begriffsdefinitionen. Da kann man die in der Regel ganz günstig definieren und dann im Text nur noch Abkürzungen verwenden. Wobei ich zum Beispiel OOP immer ausschreiben würde - HTML oder C# hingegen nicht ;) Bisher haben Kunden in der Regeln meine Dokumente für ihre hervorragende Lesbarkeit gelobt, so dass ich durchaus gewillt bin, weiterzumachen wie bisher. Mich interessiert das so gesehen eher allgemein, auch wie das vielleicht anderswo läuft.

Comment: Gleicher Blickwinkel, gleicher Standpunkt. Mich stören in Fließtexten "normale" Abkürzungen ganz ungemein - ich finde sie hinderlich und sie verlangsamen den Lesefluss. Und irgendwie komme ich nicht umhin, dabei zu denken, dass derjenige zu faul war, die Wörter auszuschreiben. Mit anderen Worten, ihm war seine Zeit wichtiger als meine. Und mit diesem Gedanken im Hinterkopf schreibe ich _mein_ "Prosa".