# Welche Abkürzung für »gegebenenfalls«?

Tags: word-choice, abbreviation

Die mir geläufige Abkürzung von *gegebenenfalls* lautet *ggfs.* Heute früh stolperte ich allerdings über [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/347/555), in der *ggf.* verwendet wird.

Sind beide Varianten für den täglichen Gebrauch gültig (natürlich ohne beide Varianten in einem Text zu mischen), oder ist eine der anderen vorzuziehen?

Comment: [Abkürzugen für gegebenenfalls](http://abkuerzungen.woxikon.de/abkuerzung/ggf..php); ich denke ggf. und ggfs. sind die geläufigsten, wobei ich ausschließlich ggf. verwende.

Comment: Mir ist ggf. sicher geläufiger, und ggfs. hätte ich spontan auch als "falsch" angesehen. Also praktisch umgekehrt zu takri.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht... ich finde alle Abkürzungen, die auf das b verzichten irgendwie ein wenig amputiert. Mein Favorit ist ggbfs. Ein langes Wort verdient eine lange Abkürzung :)

Comment: @Emanuel ggbfs? Das habe ich ja noch nie gehört ...

Comment: Vielleicht führen wir noch eine Quote für die `l` ein, immerhin sind es zwei: ggbfls. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Laut Duden wird *[gegebenenfalls](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gegebenenfalls)* mit *ggf.* abgekürzt. Auch listet der Duden *[ggf](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ggf_)* aber nicht *[ggfs](http://www.duden.de/suchen/sprachwissen/ggfs)*.

Answer (score 16):

*Ggf.* ist die häufiger verwendete Abkürzung

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Keine Antwort zu der Frage, aber ich finde es dennoch interessant und möchte es hier hinzufügen.

Das Wort *gegebenenfalls* hat seit dem späten 18. Jahrhunderten einen stetigen Zuwachs in der Verwendung. Die Abkürzung *ggf* kommt erst seit 1940 vor, was aber - denke ich - nicht zu dem zeitgleichen "Einbruch" von *gegebenenfalls* geführt hat. Höchstens tangential.

Die Abkürzung *ggfs* kommt erst wesentlich später auf, zur selben Zeit aber führt sich ein neues Wort in den deutschen Sprachschatz ein (was in der Umgangssprache jedoch wesentlich häufiger vorkommt, als es das ngram darstellt): *gegebenfalls*

Sowohl *ggfs* als auch *gegebenfalls* (was auch nach 20 Jahren Verwendung noch nicht den Weg in den regulären Wortschatz gefunden hat) sind aber nahezu vernachlässigbar, im Falle des Letzteren ja sogar falsch.

Die Abkürzung *ggf* ist aber insbesondere in den 90ern an die relative Häufigkeit von *gegebenenfalls* herangekommen und ist daher - imho - die zu bevorzugene Abkürzung.

[image]

Comment: sorry, aber _gegebenfalls_ habe ich noch NIE gehört.

Comment: Die Grafik zeigt gerade nicht einen stetigen Zuwachs. Da ist ein kräftiger Einschnitt um 1940 und eine lange Durststrecke von etwa 1955 bis 1990. @tuergeist: Wahrscheinlich weil es niemand sagt.

Comment: Ach herm - Immer diese Goldwaage... ... ... Achja, dafür dass es nie jmd sagt, beeindruckend, dass es alleine im Jahr 1998 [431 schriftliche Nachweise](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gegebenfalls%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1998,cd_max:1998&lr=lang_de) gibt

Comment: Und das Wort steht im Duden in der Kategorie häufig falsch geschriebener Wörter und auch andere Portale haben den Begriff [gegeben(en)falls](http://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/gegebenfalls.shtml) aufgenommen.

Comment: Ich rede ja nicht von den 3 kl. Dellen von 1920 bis 1940. Ein Rückgang um rd. 1/3, und dann ein Rückgang über fast 40 Jahre, das nennst Du Goldwaage? Genausogut kann man sagen die Entwicklung ist Spiralförmig mit kleinen Pirouetten.

Comment: *"Gegebenfalls"* könnte auch eine Manifestation des "Banana"-Problems sein; siehe dazu die Geschichte des kleinen Mädchens, das sagte "I know how to spell ‘banana’, but I don't know when to stop".